# Find nth element by tag name within element found by ID using XPath or CssSelector

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I need to grab the third span element, inside an A element, that is also inside an LI element that has an ID. I want to use the ID to first find the LI element, then within that, find the 3rd span element. HTML example:

```
<li id='MyID'>
<a href="MyHRef">
<span>first span</span>
<span>second span</span>
<span>third span</span>
</a>
</li>
```

I tried the following, but I dont think I have it written correctly:

```
public readonly By Menu_ProgramMatchingNumber = By.XPath("li[@id='MyID']/following-sibling::span[3]");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to XPath syntax:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

You may want to use: `//li[@id='MyID']/a/span[3]`

Or more specific: `//li[@id='MyID']/a[@href='MyHRef']/span[3]`

Comment: I edited the original post to include an A tag. If you edit your answer to include this A tag, I will mark this as the answer. By.XPath("//li[@id='ap-menu-program-matching']/a/span[3]")

Comment: @MikeJohnston,  just updated the answer to reflect your latest change in question.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS:

```
By.CssSelector("li#MyID a > span:nth-of-type(3)")
```

Comment: You should probably use `"li#MyID > a > span:nth-of-type(3)"` to be extra specific since you can be.

Comment: the *potential* problem with that, is in my years of experience, the `li` is much more likely to be changed than the `a`. by eliminating the `>` from the li to the `a`, you could save some heartache, say if they added `<li><i class="glyphicon"></i><a>...</a></li>`  but yes, both will work assuming that it doesn't change. :)  thanks @JeffC

Comment: although, now that i think about it - both are likely to change.  i typically refrain from using direct children as much as i can because of the brittleness :)

Comment: I guess it's a matter of perspective. From my point of view, I'd rather be as specific as possible and know when it breaks. If it's less specific, it might change and fail but not be clear *why* it failed... you might still get an element but not the one you expected. Neither is wrong... it's more a matter, I think, of knowing what's most likely to succeed in your own environment.

Comment: absolutely :)   thanks for chiming in.  hopefully this discussion can help others determine what's best for them!